# Javascript Onclick Flex-Basis Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm building my first piece of Javascript code to implement into my website and I'm running into a problem. I'm hoping to select multiple DIVs with the same piece of Javascript Onclick code and transition it to grow and shrink as specified by the CSS. So far I've been having problems with the flex-basis transition after the first click (shrinking doesn't transition smoothly), selecting the individual DIVs (as each is a different size they need different ID's so I'm currently using event.target), tracking the clicks to each individual DIV (I'm currently am using a global variable to track the clicks) and selecting just the DIV not the content of the DIV (the H2 or LI as with event.target). I'm hoping someone could help me with these problems in Javascript and not Jquery as I'm looking at this from an educational perspective.

Here's the HTML

```
  <article onclick="imageClick(event)" id="five"  style="background: url(images/mountain_range.jpg) center/cover">
  <h2 class="name">5</h2>
  <li class="details">$</li>
</article>


<section onclick="imageClick(event)" id="eight" style="background: url(images/mountain_range.jpg) center/cover">
  <h2 class="name">8</h2>
    <li class="details">$</li>
</section>

<section onclick="imageClick(event)" id="elleven" style="background: url(images/mountain_range.jpg) center/cover">
  <h2 class="name">11</h2>
  <li class="details">$</li>
</section>

<section onclick="imageClick(event)" id="sixteen" style="background: url(images/mountain_range.jpg) center/cover">
  <h2 class="name">16</h2>
    <li class="details">$</li>
</section>
```

and the Javascript

```
  var firstClick = true;
  function imageClick(article) {
      if (firstClick) {
        event.target.style.WebkitFlexBasis = "95vw"; // Safari 6.1+
        event.target.style.flexBasis = "95vw";
        firstClick = false;
      } else {
        event.target.style.WebkitFlexBasis = "auto"; // Safari 6.1+
        event.target.style.flexBasis = "auto";
        firstClick = true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why you put <li> inside <section> and <article>? This is not correct HTML. And please update the css also.

Comment: Please do add your CSS code for this part. :)